# How to include an integer value in a SQL (Delete) statement in delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, sql-delete, delphi-2010

In the database the DoctorID is a integer column. Neither of the edited out "//" lines of code work. I would really appreciate it if someone could show me how to correctly specify integer values in a SQL statement.

```
procedure TForm1.btnDeleteDocClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iID : Integer;
begin
  iID := StrToInt (InputBox('Delete Doctor','Please enter in your Doctor ID',''));
  with dmHospital do
  begin
    qryDoctors.SQL.Clear;
    //qryDoctors.SQL.Add('DELETE FROM Doctors WHERE DoctorID = iID ' ) ;
    //qryDoctors.SQL.Add('DELETE FROM Doctors WHERE DoctorID = ' + QuotedStr(iID));
    qryDoctors.ExecSQL;
    qryDoctors.SQL.Clear;
    qryDoctors.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Doctors');
    qryDoctors.Open;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't know which database components you're using, but search for how to use parameters in your SQL statements. Normally you would write `:Param01` in your sentence, and then pass the value in some way

Comment: `InputBox()` returns the `ADefault` parameter value if the user cancels the dialog. In this case, that is a blank string. Or, use `InputQuery()` instead, which returns a `Boolean` indicating whether the dialog was accepted or canceled. But the user can still enter a blank value. Either way, you should check for invalid input before preparing the SQL statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with

```
qryDoctors.SQL.Add('DELETE FROM Doctors WHERE DoctorID = iID ' )
```

is that it doesn't introduce the value of the variable `iID` into the DELETE statement, as you've obviously gathered.

Equally, the problem with

```
qryDoctors.SQL.Add('DELETE FROM Doctors WHERE DoctorID = ' + QuotedStr(iID))
```

is that it surrounds the value of iID with quotes, so that what the Sql engine which executes the DELETE statement actually sees is something like

```
DELETE FROM Doctors WHERE DoctorID = '99'
```

but DoctorID is an Integer column not a string one.

So, since your ID column is an integer column type, try this instead (but see below about the perils of Sql Injection):

```
qryDoctors.SQL.Add('DELETE FROM Doctors WHERE DoctorID = ' + iID);
```

Iow, you don't need quotes around integer values.

A parameterized version of your `DELETE` statement would be a better solution:

```
qryDoctors.SQL.Text := 'DELETE FROM Doctors WHERE DoctorID = :DoctorID';
qryDoctors.ParamByName('DoctorID').Value := StrToInt(iID);
```

One reason this is better is that it's immune to Sql Injection (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), whereas your way of doing it, by allowing the user to specify part of the SQL using the InputQuery and then concatenating it with the other DELETE text, is not.  In fact, concatenating user input into a SQL statement is **exactly** the thing which allows the Sql Injection exploit - for instance a malicious user can tack another statement (or more) onto the end of the one you're building, e.g. `DROP TABLE Employee` (or worse).  The opportunity for this user-subversion of the Sql statement never arises when the query is parameterised.

Fwiw, the reason I personally don't like using the `Value` property of a TParameter is that it's a variant, so subverts data-typing on the value specified.

Btw, `iID` isn't a very good name for a variable that's actually a string.  The 'i' prefix usually leads readers to expect an integer.

Comment: `qryDoctors.SQL.Add('DELETE FROM Doctors WHERE DoctorID = ' + iID);` That's a SQL-injection hole.

Comment: @Johan:  I was going to mention Sql Injection, but couldn't be fagged. I will add a mention of it in a mo, thanks.

Comment: @Johan:  Done and btw your "worse than useless" comment on the other answer was a perfectly fair point.

Comment: @MartynA: I fixed the iID Integer part, I was playing with different ideas and forgot to change it back. I tried : ` qryDoctors.SQL.Text := 'DELETE FROM Doctors WHERE DoctorID = :DoctorID';
    qryDoctors.ParamByName('DoctorID').AsInteger := iID; ` But it says "'TParameter' does not contain a member named 'AsInteger'"                   I'm not too worried about SQL injection but thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @OceanKnight:  Sorry, I missed that, it's in a bit of code someone else added.  Anyway, the error message is correct:  replace `AsString` by `Value`.

Comment: "I'm not too worried about SQL injection" You should be. But in addition to being safe, parameterized queries are also much faster, because the DB can cache parameterized queries and it cannot cache concat queries.